# How to match class properties to enum?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the following (`cat` is an `NSUInteger` corresponding to the `enum`:

```
   if((cat == enum_cat1) & self.cat1) ||
      (cat == enum_cat2) & self.cat2) ||
      (cat == enum_cat3) & self.cat3) ||
      (cat == enum_cat4) & self.cat4))
```

Basically I have an enum of categories and a bunch of boolean class properties that correspond to those properties. Whenever the property matching `cat` is true, I want the entire `if` statement to be true. **There must be a better way to do this. What is it?**

Comment: You want `&&`, not `&`. Are there any other values for the `enum`, that don't correspond to properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping between the `enum` values and the property names, using either a `switch` statement or a dictionary, then get the property name and use KVC to check its value.

```
NSDictionary * catToProp = @{ @enum_cat1 : @"cat1",
                              // etc.
                            };

NSString * propName = catToProp[@cat];

if( [[self valueForKey:propName] boolValue] ){
}
```

You could also use an array:

```
NSString * catToProp = { [enum_cat1] = @"cat1",
                         // etc.
                       };
```

taking advantage of C's [named initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a bitmask:

```
typedef enum Category {
    Category0 = 0 << 0,
    Category1 = 1 << 0,
    Category2 = 1 << 1,
    Cagegory3 = 1 << 2
};

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (assign) Category category;
...
@end
```

Then test with:

```
if (self.category & Category1) {
    // Do first thing
} else if ((self.category & Category2) || (self.category & Category3)) {
    // Do second or third thing
}
```

or:

```
- (void)doCategory:(Category)category
{
    if (self.category & category) {
        // Do thing
    }
}
```

Setting it like this:

```
SomeClass *someClass = [SomeClass new];
someClass.category = Category1|Category3;
[someClass doCategory:Category3];
```

Note the difference between `&` and `&&`.

Comment: It seems that one of us has misinterpreted the question. Which one remains to be seen :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, my answer doesn't directly address the question, but provides an incite on how I'd approach the issue.  Having separate boolean fields rings alarm bells for a start, especially if comparison with some `enum` is required.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same :-)

Comment: Oh, I see; you're suggesting a new mode of attack. I admit I went for the literal fix, assuming there was a good reason for it.